# Why SoftDelete won't fake the deleted row?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, soft-delete

Can somebody tell me why using `delete()` method won't delete the selected row in table? `SoftDelete` works well but the row that has been soft delete is still exist in the table. I'm expecting my table row will be hide or deleted but it can't. Any tips or help would appreciated! :) I `SoftDelete` my table like this.

Controller:

```
public function hideApprovalsDocument(Request $request, Document $id)
{
    //Getting the request in the View.
    $id = $request->get('softDelete');
    $hide = Document::findOrFail($id)->where('id', '=', $id);
    $hide->delete();

    return redirect()->back();

}

public function documentsSentForApproval()
{

    $pendingDocuments = DB::table('approvals_document')
        ->select('documents.title', 'documents.content', 'documents.id as documentId', 
            'categories.category_type',
            'users.username', 'approvals_document.created_at',
            'approvals_document.id', 'approvals_document.approver_id', 'approvals_document.requestedBy')
        ->join('documents', 'documents.id', '=', 'approvals_document.document_id')
        ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'documents.category_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'approvals_document.approver_id')
        ->where('approver_id', '=', Auth::id())
        ->where('documents.deleted_at', '=', null)
        ->orWhere('requestedBy', '=', Auth::id())
        ->orderBy('approvals_document.id', '=', 'desc')
        ->paginate(10);

    return view ('document.pending')
        ->with('pendingDocuments', $pendingDocuments);

}
```

Comment: How did you render your table row? I mean, how did you get your `Document` records on your table row?

Comment: @Alfa Did you mean how I query it? To get all the records in my row?

Comment: Yeah, how did you query it?

Comment: Soft delete only works with Eloquent. Here you are using query builder. Change ->where('documents.deleted_at', '=', null) to ->whereNull('documents.deleted_at')

Comment: @MD.MuntasirRahman  `->whereNull('documents.deleted_at')` still returns me a same view it didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you please change the join query to below
->join('documents', function ($join)  {
                $join->on('documents.id', '=', 'approvals_document.document_id')
                    ->whereNull('documents.deleted_at');
            })

Comment: @shoieb0101 Hey this works well. Can you post your answer so I can accept it? So anybody can have reference :D

Comment: sure, I've posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please change the join query to below

```
->join('documents', function ($join) `{ $join->on('documents.id', '=','approvals_document.document_id') 
->whereNull('documents.deleted_at'); })`
```

Comment: Hi! Why using this join `->join('documents', 'documents.id', '=', 'approvals_document.document_id')` and adding `whereNull('documents.deleted_at')` won't work? What's they're difference?

Comment: @Francisunoxx if you need to set a where clause on joined table, it needs to be in a nested query. Otherwise it pulls all the records from the joined table, I guess

Comment: I think laravel confuse when you didn't nested it. Not sure hehe.

Answer (score 1):

Soft delete won't delete the row. It'll set a timestamp for the `deleted_at` field and eloquent will ignore any rows which have a value set for the field `deleted_at`. If you implemented soft delete and want to permanently delete a row, try using 'forceDelete()'

```
$hide->forceDelete();
```

Comment: But this will delete my data and will no longer be restore.

Comment: Yes, if you want to keep your data then just use the regular delete() method. It'll not the delete the data from database, just set a timestamp on deleted_at field. When you query via Eloquent, rows having value in deleted_at fields will be ignored. You can always retrieve soft deleted rows and set them as active rows. [source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#soft-deleting)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do any comparison to `NULL` value in Laravel SQL via `where` method. You may use `whereRaw` method:

```
public function documentsSentForApproval()
{

    $pendingDocuments = DB::table('approvals_document')
        ->select('documents.title', 'documents.content', 'documents.id as documentId', 
            'categories.category_type',
            'users.username', 'approvals_document.created_at',
            'approvals_document.id', 'approvals_document.approver_id', 'approvals_document.requestedBy')
        ->join('documents', function ($join) {
            $join->on('documents.id', '=', 'approvals_document.document_id')
                ->whereRaw('documents.deleted_at IS NULL');
        })
        ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'documents.category_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'approvals_document.approver_id')
        ->where('approver_id', '=', Auth::id())
        ->orWhere('requestedBy', '=', Auth::id())
        ->orderBy('approvals_document.id', '=', 'desc')
        ->paginate(10);

    return view ('document.pending')
        ->with('pendingDocuments', $pendingDocuments);

}
```

#### Update

Joining soft-deleted records must be modified

Comment: Why this deleted my record when adding `whereRaw('documents.deleted_at IS NULL')`?

Comment: Not true: there is a method called whereNull().

Comment: @JanWillem of course that method will works too. but I prefer `whereRaw` to increase verbosity.

Comment: @Francisunoxx It shouldn't deleted your record from database, because it's a readonly operation. BTW, does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @Alfa I don't know why it's deleted in my database. I'll check my query again.

Comment: @Francisunoxx Check your `hideApprovalsDocument` method. Make sure you use `delete` not `forceDelete`. And also check your `Document`, you have to use `SoftDelete` trait inside it.

Comment: @Alfa Yeah gonna check my `hideApprovalsDocument` method. I used `delete` here not `forceDelete`. It just totally deleted when adding `whereRaw('documents.deleted_at IS NULL')` in my script.

Comment: @Francisunoxx I believe it's not deleted persistently, it just hidden on your web app. Have you check your record in the database from any DBMS Client?

Comment: @Alfa Didn't notice I used `forceDelete`. I changed it to `delete` but still no changes.

Comment: Hi @Francisunoxx, I updated the answer, please let me know.

Comment: @Alfa Still analyzing your code :) As of now it gives me a error. `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::whereRaw()`. I'm having an error within `whereRaw`